# How to compile at pickest level in gcc/g++?

Tags: compiler-warnings

In "Code Complete", Steve Mcconnell suggest that "Compile code at pickiest warning level and fix all the picky compiler warning."

How can I do that when I compile my C/C++ program?

Today I mistyped `reply == see_more();` when I really mean `reply = see_more();`, so I want to figure out how to compile at a picky warning level so that I can found out this bug when I compile, but not when realize that my program doesn't work like I expect.

Comment: Have you tried the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` options to `gcc/g++` compiler?

Comment: No, I have not heard about these option,  Could you tell me something more detailed about how to use these option?@mbaitoff

Comment: Please show your compiling sequence. As you mention `gcc/g++", the simplest way is to add those options to your command line that compiles your program.